# Activate glitch level on super meatboy

Tags: super-meat-boy

I've been googling this and all I find is that the glitch world is random whenever you die, and it was recommended to go onto world 1-3 and keep suiciding to activate it.

I've been suiciding over and over probably 100+ times and she hasn't glitched a single time.

I've 100%'d the chapter, i.e. all worlds A+ and all bandages, but I can't seem to get her to glitch so that I can try the glitch world. Any ideas? I've read posts saying she does it after <10 deaths unusually, so my 100+ suiciding seems a bit excessive.

Comment: Do you know how she looks like when she glitches ? Cause if you're too fast in your suicide attempt you might have missed it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with it, it glitched on another chapter a couple of times. This one though is insane, I've replayed the entire chapter about 6 times from start to finish, which gave me the rare achievement, as well as the achievement for not dying on light, I'm working on dark world not dying. I've suicided 300+ times now and it hasn't glitched once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this, I didn't realise the level appeared left of the start and once unlocked stayed unlocked. I'm an idiot.